# Improving visibility of text in scanned image

Tags: image-processing

I have as example the image below and would like to improve it in such a way that mainly the text is visible and the noisy background is removed.

How can that be done best?[image]

Comment: Related: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1934/291

Comment: `ImageAdjust[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/vWX65.jpg"], {4.25, -.2}]` as a starting point.

Comment: You'll find many useful functions here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SegmentationAnalysis.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to make a functional form of [nikie's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1934/291), which can't be marked as a duplicate as it's on another SE site,

```
improve[img_] :=
  ImageCrop@
  Binarize@Image[
    ImageData[img]/ImageData[Closing[img, DiskMatrix[5]]]]

improve@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWX65.jpg"]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... incredible

Comment: Don't forget to follow nikie's link above and upvote that post!

Comment: Here might be a good place to point out the existence of `LocalAdaptiveBinarize`. Its documentation has an example with highly variable text contrast, just in case source material is less than stellar in quality.

Comment: @kirma, I had trouble getting a decent image that way.  I used `Manipulate` like in the example, but I can't get rid of the shading in the corner:  `LocalAdaptiveBinarize[
 Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/vWX65.jpg"], 23, {0.6, 0.43, 0.25}]`

Comment: @JasonB Like most heuristic image processing algorithms, sometimes it works, sometimes not...

Answer (score 5):

If a grayscale image is needed, we can do as in Jason answer but replacing the binarize with an ImageAdjust.

```
src = ColorConvert[Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWX65.jpg", "Grayscale"];
white = Closing[src, DiskMatrix[5]];
imgWithUniformBkg = Image[ImageData[src]/ImageData[white]];
ImageAdjust@imgWithUniformBkg
```

But this results in an image that is too light:

[image]

A much better results is found after using a manipulate to explore the possible settings:

```
Manipulate[
    Labeled[ImageAdjust[imgWithUniformBkg, Append[cb, g]], Append[cb, g]], 
    {cb, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {g, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Gustavo, isn't this exactly the same method, from the same source, with the same implementation [shown by Jason in his previous answer above](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105570/27951)?

Comment: I had to add the ImageAdjust with {0, 0.5, 10} parameters in order to get good results.

Comment: Jason answered while I was also writing my response. Yes it is almost the same (mine is not binarized), so I guess that I should delete this answer.

Comment: Whether to delete it or not is of course up to you. Perhaps you could differentiate it further? Your solution returns a grayscale image rather than a black and white one, perhaps you could point that out; maybe your need for `ImageAdjust` stemmed from there?

Comment: I rewrote my answer with an emphasis on the ImageAdjust

Comment: That's very nice indeed! (+1)